# openGL textures that are not 2^x in dimention

Tags: c++, opengl, ldf

I'm trying to display a picture in an openGL environment. The picture's origninal dimensions are 3648x2432, and I want to display it with a 256x384 image. The problem is, 384 is not a power of 2, and when I try to display it, it looks stretched. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three ways of doing this that I know of -

- The one Albert suggested (resize it until it fits).
- Subdivide the texture into 2**n-sized rectangles, and piece them together in some way.
- See if you can use `GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two`. It's probably best to avoid it though, since it looks like it's an Xorg-specific extension.

Comment: Option 2 is great - prevents loss of fidelity

Answer (score 2):

You can resize your texture so it *is* a power of two (skew your texture so that when it is mapped onto the object it looks correct).

Comment: I am under the impression that textures are always a power of two because the hardware would use the same amount of resources anyways. But I could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`ARB_texture_rectangle` is probably what you're looking for. It lets you bind to `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, and you can load an image with non power-of-2 dimensions. Be aware that your texture coordinates will range from [0..w]x[0..h] instead of [0..1]x[0..1].

Answer (score 0):

If GL_EXT_texture_rectangle is true then use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT for the first param in glEnable() and GLBindTexture() calls.